# Where is kong.conf file?

Tags: api-gateway, kong

I installed kong as per the official installation guide. 
And now to start I should give the `kong.conf` file ? I cant find where it is .

`kong start [-c /path/to/kong.conf]`

Comment: Just a helpful note for anyone on versions < 0.9.0rc1 that it used to be kong.yml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it. It was in `/etc/kong/kong.config.default` !

Inspired by [this](https://github.com/Kong/homebrew-kong/issues/53)

Answer (score 8):

based on the documentation [here](https://docs.konghq.com/install/macos/?_ga=2.58182184.30626737.1581437497-576381536.1581437497)

1. create new directory `kong` in `/etc`
2. download `kong.conf.default` [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Kong/kong/master/kong.conf.default)
3. copy that file to `kong.conf` inside `/etc/kong`